# Axioms of equivalence relation in terms of the subset $R$

Tags: equivalence-relations

..An equivalence relation on $S$ is determined by the subset $R$ of $ S \times S$ consisting of those pairs $\left(a,b\right)$ such that $a \sim b$. Write the axioms for an equivalence relation in terms of the subset $R$.

Since I was not getting any clue I took $S$ to be $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and defined $a\sim b$ if $a+b=2k$. Clearly this is an equivalence relation. Then $S=\{(1,1),(1,3),(3,1),(2,2),(2,4),(4,2),(4,4)\}$.

Then I defined $ a\sim b$ if $a \lt b$. This relation is only transitive. Here $S=\{(2,1),(3,1),(3,2),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)\}$.

Again I defined $ a\sim b$ if $a \le b$. This relation is reflexive and transitive but not symmetric. Here $S=\{(2,1),(3,1),(3,2),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$

Based on these I defined the following: $\sim$ is said to be an equivalence on $S$ if the following hold:

(i) $(a,a) \in R$ for all $a$ in $S$ (Reflexive)

(ii) If $(a,b) \in R$, then $(b,a) \in R$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $S$(Symmetric)

(iii) If $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$, then $(a,c) \in R$ for all $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $S$ (Transitive)

Is this the correct one??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Yes, those are the right axioms.

Comment: @AdamHughes Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

A question from Michael Artin - Algebra (2nd Edition), Exercise 2.7.2

The equivalence relation in the question is abstract and needs no specifying, it’s purely a practice for realising the three axioms (transitive, symmetric and reflexive) *in terms of* the subset $R$. $R$’s 'being the subset $R$ of $ S \times S$ consisting of those pairs $\left(a,b\right)$ such that $a \sim b$' *stipulates* the form for realisation. I.e. we know that $a \sim b$ is written as $\left(a,b\right)$, hence other expressions follow.

Your answer is correct but the exemplification is IMO unnecessary, and I should have commented rather than written an answer had it not been for the lack of reputations

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1979731)

Comment: @E.Joseph I do not see why this does not answer the question. The question asks "are these the correct axioms" and the answer is "yes", which this answer says. It also points out that the example illustration is unnecessary, which is true.